# waiting for thread with timeout: freeze

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I don't understand anything now. Consider I have next piece of code (simplified version):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

const auto k_sleep = std::chrono::seconds{3};
const auto k_wait = std::chrono::seconds{1};
const auto k_repeats = 20u;

void test()
{
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable c;
    bool processed = false;

    std::thread worker{[&]() {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(k_sleep);

            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
            processed = true;
            lock.unlock();
            c.notify_one();
        }};

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    if(c.wait_for(lock, k_wait, [&processed]() {
            return processed;
        }))
    {
        worker.join();
        std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        worker.detach();
        std::cout << "timeout" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    for(auto i = 0u; i < k_repeats; ++i)
        test();
}
```

Few questions:

- are there any deadlocks ?
- am I using `condition_variable` (and all other stuff relative to `thread`) correctly ?
- is there UB ?
- if everything OK, how many times `timeout` will be printed ?

As you can see, I'm running thread and waiting for it (using `condition_variable`) some time. Wait time is less then thread's executing time.

With both VC++ (Visual Studio 2015, v 19.00.23026) and g++ (v 4.8.2) I have `timeout` 2 times printed and then I'm stuck on `worker.join()` under debugger. If I will increase `k_sleep` to something big (relatively to `k_wait` with small loops count), for example, 30 seconds - everything will be fine.

So, why this happens ? If I do something incorrectly please explain me the correct way. Thanks

Comment: You should not call  `worker.detach();`, but `join()` in any case.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, but I don't want to wait for thread in case of timeout. How can I do this without calling `detach()` on thread ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, oh, I understand - I'm using `condition_variable` that was destroyed. Thanks

Comment: Some native thread implementations provide a `kill()` function. You can use that with the native thread handle.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I'm killing thread and then call `join()` on `std::thread` instance, am I correct ? And can you answer the question or mark it somehow ? Thank you

Comment: Looks like we already have a good number of useful information collected on the site: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5Dkill+a+thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problems with memory management there:

1. Capturing variables by reference in lambda that passed to a new thread.
2. All variables (`m`, `c` and `processed`) are allocated on the stack, and they will go out of scope when you detach a worker thread. So, when the thread wake up, it will access garbage.

So, you need to allocate you data on the heap and make sure you do not capture variables by reference. I always prefer to pass data explicitly into `std::thread`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>

const auto k_sleep = std::chrono::seconds{ 3 };
const auto k_wait = std::chrono::seconds{ 1 };
const auto k_repeats = 20u;


struct Data
{
   std::mutex m;
   std::condition_variable c;
   bool processed = false;
};

void test()
{
   auto data = std::make_shared<Data>();

   auto run = [](std::shared_ptr<Data> i_data) {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(k_sleep);

      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(i_data->m);
      i_data->processed = true;
      lock.unlock();
      i_data->c.notify_one();
   };

   std::thread worker{ run, data };

   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(data->m);
   if (data->c.wait_for(lock, k_wait, [&data]() {
      return data->processed;
   }))
   {
      worker.join();
      std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
   }
   else
   {
      worker.detach();
      std::cout << "timeout" << std::endl;
   }
}

int main()
{
   for (auto i = 0u; i < k_repeats; ++i)
      test();
}
```

Comment: thanks, I already did the same. Even don't know how to explain such an easy mistake :)